# Tkinter: Using entry value in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When file1.py runs and the submit button is hit, the submit method will return entry.get() value, which is fine. However, if I wanted too transfer the entry.get() too another python file when the submit button is hit. Is this possible?

file1.py

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def submit():
    return entry.get()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
submit_button = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = submit)
submit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

file2.py

```
import file1 as f1
from tkinter import messagebox
var = submit()
if var == "test":
   messagebox.showinfo("Hello")
```

This is what I'm wanting to do but having no luck with it atm.

Comment: What is the other file actually doing? Can you show us the code there?

Comment: For the purpose of this, I was trying to just print entry.get() in the console through file2.py

Comment: The easiest way is probably to write it to a file, and let the other python script read that file

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the value to a function that you have defined in the other file like this.

**p1.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from p2 import new_print

root = Tk()

def submit():
    new_print(entry.get())

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
submit_button = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = submit)
submit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**p2.py**

```
value_from_p1 = None

def new_print(value):
    global value_from_p1
    value_from_p1 = value
    print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question, on p2.py how can the value be set to a global variable so that it can be used everywhere in p2.py?

Comment: @monto Edited the answer. Whenever you need to use, just use `global value_from_p1`.